# Find plugin's jar from a nexsus public repository

Tags: java, gradle, nexus

I am trying to get the plugin's jars from a nexus repository **https://repository.axelor.com/nexus/public/**

the plugin: "com.axelor.app" In the .gradle folder I only find a pom file **com.axelor.app.gradle.plugin-5.4.13.pom**

Comment: Have you looked into their documentation: https://docs.axelor.com/adk/5.3/dev-guide/application/index.html ? How does your build.gradle look like?

Comment: I read the documentation I still can't find the jar that contains the plugin.
this is the build.gradle https://github.com/axelor/open-suite-webapp/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: Do you mean the plugin jar file that gradle downloaded? https://repository.axelor.com/nexus/#browse/browse:maven-public:com%2Faxelor%2Faxelor-gradle%2F5.4.13 . Probably it is in one of the gradle caches under `~/.gradle`. Also: https://repository.axelor.com/nexus/public/com/axelor/axelor-gradle/axelor-gradle-5.4.13.jar

Comment: yes I am trying to find that jar. there is nothing relating to the plugin in the ~/.gradle folder.
I don't know where is gradle searching the plugin.